# \Underbar changing the style of font but \bar not, why?

Tags: fonts

The **x** alphabets should be of the same size and style. You can see below an ugly change in the style of **x**. How can I keep the font profile such as the size and style the same?

[image]

**Ugly example** where the size changes with `\frac{\bar x_i+\underbar x_i}{2}`.

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,english,titlepage,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}     %For theorems
\usepackage{amssymb}    %For things, \mathbb R.
\usepackage{bm}         %For bolding with greek letters


\begin{document}

\begin{align}
l_i &= \bar x_i-\underbar x_i \\
\hat x_i &= 0.5 (\bar x_i+\underbar x_i)
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\underbar` switches to text mode since it boxes its contents. You can use `\underline` instead.

Comment: `\bar` is declared as a maths accent by LaTeX whereas `\underbar` is a regular text command. `fontmath.ltx` contains `\DeclareMathAccent{\bar}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"16}` whereas `latex.ltx` includes `\def\underbar#1{\underline{\sbox\tw@{#1}\dp\tw@\z@\box\tw@}}`.

Comment: $$\underbar$$ why doesn't it work here? is it possible to put it in math exchange somehow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are making it harder than it has to be. `\underbar{$x$}` resolves it without further packages or new commands. To get equal length use `\overline{x}` instead of `\bar{x}`. The bars are longer than in the above, but equal.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please provide an example similarly to what Gonzalo and egreg did? This would help a lot future readers in understanding the validity of your approach.

Comment: $$\underbar$$ why doesn't it work here? is it possible to put it in math exchange somehow?

Answer (score 25):

The difference is that `\underbar` switches to text mode when it boxes its contents. The definition in the kernel is

```
\def\underbar#1{\underline{\sbox\tw@{#1}\dp\tw@\z@\box\tw@}}
```

On the other side, `\bar` is a math accent:

```
\DeclareMathAccent{\bar}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"16}
```

You can define a variation of the kernel's `\underbar` that boxes the contents in math mode:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,english,titlepage,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}     %For theorems
\usepackage{amssymb}    %For things, \mathbb R.
\usepackage{bm}         %For bolding with greek letters

\makeatletter
\def\munderbar#1{\underline{\sbox\tw@{$#1$}\dp\tw@\z@\box\tw@}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\newbox\mybox
\begin{align}
l_i &= \bar{x}_i-\munderbar{x}_i \\
\hat x_i &= 0.5 (\bar{x}_i+\munderbar{x}_i)
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, as you can see in the image the result is not very good. A better alternative is to use the `accents` package and its `\underaccent` command:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,english,titlepage,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}     %For theorems
\usepackage{amssymb}    %For things, \mathbb R.
\usepackage{bm}         %For bolding with greek letters
\usepackage{accents}

\newcommand\munderbar[1]{%
  \underaccent{\bar}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\newbox\mybox
\begin{align}
l_i &= \bar{x}_i-\munderbar{x}_i \\
\hat x_i &= 0.5 (\bar{x}_i+\munderbar{x}_i)
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I chose to use underline because not wanting to import too much packages even though it looks a bit nicer. +1 and thank you!

Comment: $$\underbar$$ why doesn't it work here? is it possible to put it in math exchange somehow?

Answer (score 14):

You have two choices: either use `\underline` or the `accents` package and its `\underaccent` feature; I'll show both.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{accents}

\newcommand{\ubar}[1]{\underaccent{\bar}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
l_i &= \bar{x}_i-\underline{x}_i \\
\hat{x}_i &= 0.5 (\bar{x}_i+\underline{x}_i)
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
l_i &= \bar{x}_i-\ubar{x}_i \\
\hat{x}_i &= 0.5 (\bar{x}_i+\ubar{x}_i)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Avoid `\bar x` or `\hat x`; with braces it may seem more difficult to type, but it adds to clarity.

Comment: Why do I need `\usepackage{accents}` when `underline` works without it?

Comment: @hhh `accents` is necessary for the second example

Comment: $$\underbar$$ why doesn't it work here? is it possible to put it in math exchange somehow?

Comment: @CharlieParker `\underbar` is a text command.

Comment: @egreg what are the consequences of that?

Comment: @CharlieParker If you try, for example, `$\underbar{\alpha}$`, you'll get an error, because the argument to `\underbar` is managed in text, not math, mode.