# Article and Beamer Accent Problem

Tags: beamer, fonts, article, sans-serif

This is a follow up question [to this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/540118/bar-format-not-correct/540126?noredirect=1#comment1365909_540126).

So after some experimentation, I realized that no matter which font package I put, `beamer` always has a problem with the formatting the accents, whereas `article` doesn't.

Article code:

```
\documentclass[12 pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\usepackage{sansmathaccent} %To get the bar on top aligned correctly
\usepackage{accents} %For underbar
\newcommand\munderbar[1]{%
    \underaccent{\bar}{#1}} %making the underbar
%Source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163280/underbar-changing-the-style-of-font-but-bar-not-why

\renewcommand{\left}{\mleft}
\renewcommand{\right}{\mright}
\begin{document}
    $$\munderbar{u}_i \leq u_i\left(t\right)\leq \bar{u}_i$$
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Beamer code (with original font):

```
\documentclass[12 pt,handout,notheorems]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[a4paper,landscape]
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage{sansmathaccent} %To get the bar on top aligned correctly
\usepackage{accents} %For underbar
\newcommand\munderbar[1]{%
    \underaccent{\bar}{#1}} %making the underbar
%Source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163280/underbar-changing-the-style-of-font-but-bar-not-why

\renewcommand{\left}{\mleft}
\renewcommand{\right}{\mright}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        $$\munderbar{u}_i \leq u_i\left(t\right)\leq \bar{u}_i$$
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Beamer code (with `serif`):

```
\documentclass[12 pt,handout,notheorems, serif]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[a4paper,landscape]
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage{sansmathaccent} %To get the bar on top aligned correctly
\usepackage{accents} %For underbar
\newcommand\munderbar[1]{%
    \underaccent{\bar}{#1}} %making the underbar
%Source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163280/underbar-changing-the-style-of-font-but-bar-not-why

\renewcommand{\left}{\mleft}
\renewcommand{\right}{\mright}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        $$\munderbar{u}_i \leq u_i\left(t\right)\leq \bar{u}_i$$
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

I also tried to update MikTeX, but as mentioned in the previous query, it had no effect on fixing the efficacy of `sansmathaccent` in particular. I was introduced an ad-hoc method, but I would need to do so for any letter that I use if I place an accent on it. Is there any other "general" way of tackling this problem?

Comment: It is always a struggle in terms of font: We want sans-serif in presentation but the math support is limited, and beamer replaces all Latin letters and digits using text font (by default) so the math accents break down. At least `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}` gives “correct” maths…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to avoid (not correct) the issue, could be to redefine `\bar` alltogether using `\overline`, and defining `\ubar` with `\underline`.

```
\documentclass[12 pt,handout,notheorems]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[a4paper,landscape]
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\renewcommand\bar[1]{\overline{#1}}
\newcommand\ubar[1]{\underline{#1}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        $$\ubar{u}_i \leq u_i\left(t\right)\leq \bar{u}_i$$
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]